# How to paste the generated org-id?

Tags: org-mode

`org-id-get-create` creates the header property e.g. `:ID: 22b9191c-.....` though I can't paste the appropriate link from the kill ring nor does `org-insert-link`. Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org-id-get-create` inserts the property at point. You can then get a link to it with `org-store-link` (usually bound to `C-c l` as the [manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Activation.html#Activation) recommends), and you can insert the link somewhere with `org-insert-link` (bound to `C-c C-l` by default in the Org mode keymap).

EDIT: to get `org-store-link` to prefer creating id-based links, do

```
(setq org-id-link-to-org-use-id t)
```

This variable can be `nil` (the default), `t` or it can have a couple of other values that affect whether an ID is created depending on the context. Check the doc string with `C-h v org-id-link-to-org-use-id RET`.

Comment: `C-c C-l` or `org-insert-link` inserts the header name e.g. `[[*bla][bla]]` though I'm trying to link to the id, something like `[[22b9191c...][bla]]`.

Comment: Good idea, I don't know why this feature is not exist!
Currently org mode works with text search like , As you mention if you change it with org-id it can be useful and more stable.

`URL: [[file:~/folder/filename.org::*HEAD%20Example][Trail spotting test]]` to 
`URL: [[!!HASH][Trail spotting test]]`

Comment: The feature does exist, but you need to turn it on: see the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

`org-id-copy` will copy the id of the current entry, creating it if necessary.  It can then be pasted with the usual commands (e.g. `C-y`)

Comment: Thank you, yes the id gets copied to the kill ring. Would be great if I could paste it surrounded with the necessary link brackets

Comment: You can use `C-c C-l` to start `org-insert-link` then `C-y` to paste the id you just copied into the minibuffer prompt